# How to Pass Collection View Data to a New View Controller

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, uicollectionview

I am going try be as specific as possible.

What I am trying to achieve is to have one view controller which has a collection view in it and when the user clicks on of the collection view cells, it then sends the user to another view controller which has another collection view however the items displayed in the second collection view will change depending on which collection view cell the user previously tapped. I am also using CoreData to do this. With CoreData, the task is an entity and has attributes like name etc. Will I have to change this or have a relationship between the 2 collection views?

The reason for me wanting to do this is because I am creating a productivity app for iOS and the first view controller with a collection view will be where the user can create projects, within these projects which will be displayed in a collection view, the user can then tap on one of the cells and go to the next view controller and begin to create tasks specific to that project.

How can I keep the tasks stored in a specific collection view cell and have the user create different tasks in other projects. It is sort of like Wunderlist. If anybody is confused at what I am trying to do, I can ellaborate more.

This is one of my view controllers where the data from the 'create item view controller' gets sent to via CoreData and displays it in a collection view, hope it helps:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var myCollView: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func addCore(_ sender: UIButton) {


}

var tasks : [Task] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myCollView.delegate = self
    self.myCollView.dataSource = self


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getData()
    myCollView.reloadData()

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "connectCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelTe?.text = task.name!

    self.myCollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    return cell


}

func getData() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
    }

    catch {
     print("Ahhhhhhhh")
    }

}
```

Comment: Should probably post the code you have related to this. Also, am I correct in thinking you want to pass the data from a cell to a detail view controller?

Comment: @CalebKleveter Posted my main view controllers code, and also I want to pass the data from a cell to correlate to another collection view cell in another view controller so that if that specific cell is pressed then it shows certain items and if the user presses another cell then different collection view cells are shown. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am guessing right, and upon clicking a cell on the first collection view, you want to segue to another collection view, where you will display display data according to the selected cell.

In order to achieve this, simply add `collectionView(_ collectionView:, didSelectItemAt indexPath:)` and `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` functions in your first view controller.

In the `collectionView(_ collectionView:, didSelectItemAt indexPath:)` function get the id of the task selected by determine which cell was selected, then pass this id to the second view controller in `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
            id = cell.labelTe?.text
}
```

or

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            id = tasks[indexPath.row].id
}
```

Then pass this value in your `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` function to the second viewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier"{
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
                destinationViewController.id = id
        }
    }
```

Make sure to add a var id in both your viewControllers. In the second viewController, use this id to fetch the data of the selected task that you want to display.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Simply declare a new variable `id` of your particular type in both the viewControllers. In your first viewController :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var id = ""
```

and in the second viewController

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {

var id = ""
```

Just make sure that both the variable are of same type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, also can you please just show me what you meant with creating a 'var id' in both viewControllers, I am very new to Xcode so am not to sure about fetching data etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, I declared both variables now and added the segue and didSelect however I am not sure how to fetch data from CoreData using the id. Also I am not sure how to save a task so that it saves relating to one collection view cell and not another. If you could please just help me out for this last step it would be great, my email is richardwesselsofficial@gmail.com and if you could just send me an email I could show you my project and the issue easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I am following YouTube tutorials and have recently been looking at prepareForSegue function however and still not too sure how to make a collection view cell show only tasks that have been save to it and have looked around on how to save with an identifier but had little success, I am still very new to Xcode and not sure of many concepts. Sorry for dragging out this question but if you could email me or give an example of using an id to display with CoreData. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try learning from appcoda. They offer quite nice tutorials and also books that you can purchase form them. They have covered everything from top-bottom and keep on updating with the new os. They might really help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the source, the problem is that I am developing a to-do list app and it needs to be ready for distribution by 1 March and this issue with collection view correlating to another collection view with CoreData is heavily slowing down development so is their any chance that I could send you the project or if you can just email me so I can get a better understanding of what you mean, also thank you so much for all the help and will definitely learn from AppCoda soon!